# SO_PEERCRED missing in ruby-1.8.7?

Tags: ruby, sockets, networking

Not sure how you revive the peer id of a process connecting to a UNIX socket in ruby. I checked out and not sure where the SO_PEERCRED is defined. I am using ruby-1.8.7

> > Socket.constants.sort
> >     => ["AF_APPLETALK", "AF_CCITT", "AF_CHAOS", "AF_CNT", "AF_COIP", "AF_DATAKIT", "AF_DLI", "AF_E164", "AF_ECMA", "AF_HYLINK", "AF_IMPLINK", "AF_INET", "AF_INET6", "AF_IPX", "AF_ISDN", "AF_ISO", "AF_LAT", "AF_LINK", "AF_LOCAL", "AF_MAX", "AF_NATM", "AF_NDRV", "AF_NETBIOS", "AF_NS", "AF_OSI", "AF_PPP", "AF_PUP", "AF_ROUTE", "AF_SIP", "AF_SNA", "AF_SYSTEM", "AF_UNIX", "AF_UNSPEC", "AI_ADDRCONFIG", "AI_ALL", "AI_CANONNAME", "AI_DEFAULT", "AI_MASK", "AI_NUMERICHOST", "AI_PASSIVE", "AI_V4MAPPED", "AI_V4MAPPED_CFG", "APPEND", "CREAT", "Constants", "EAI_ADDRFAMILY", "EAI_AGAIN", "EAI_BADFLAGS", "EAI_BADHINTS", "EAI_FAIL", "EAI_FAMILY", "EAI_MAX", "EAI_MEMORY", "EAI_NODATA", "EAI_NONAME", "EAI_PROTOCOL", "EAI_SERVICE", "EAI_SOCKTYPE", "EAI_SYSTEM", "EXCL", "Enumerator", "FNM_CASEFOLD", "FNM_DOTMATCH", "FNM_NOESCAPE", "FNM_PATHNAME", "FNM_SYSCASE", "INADDR_ALLHOSTS_GROUP", "INADDR_ANY", "INADDR_BROADCAST", "INADDR_LOOPBACK", "INADDR_MAX_LOCAL_GROUP", "INADDR_NONE", "INADDR_UNSPEC_GROUP", "IPPORT_RESERVED", "IPPORT_USERRESERVED", "IPPROTO_EGP", "IPPROTO_EON", "IPPROTO_GGP", "IPPROTO_HELLO", "IPPROTO_ICMP", "IPPROTO_IDP", "IPPROTO_IGMP", "IPPROTO_IP", "IPPROTO_MAX", "IPPROTO_ND", "IPPROTO_PUP", "IPPROTO_RAW", "IPPROTO_TCP", "IPPROTO_TP", "IPPROTO_UDP", "IPPROTO_XTP", "IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP", "IP_DEFAULT_MULTICAST_LOOP", "IP_DEFAULT_MULTICAST_TTL", "IP_DROP_MEMBERSHIP", "IP_HDRINCL", "IP_MAX_MEMBERSHIPS", "IP_MULTICAST_IF", "IP_MULTICAST_LOOP", "IP_MULTICAST_TTL", "IP_OPTIONS", "IP_RECVDSTADDR", "IP_RECVOPTS", "IP_RECVRETOPTS", "IP_RETOPTS", "IP_TOS", "IP_TTL", "LOCK_EX", "LOCK_NB", "LOCK_SH", "LOCK_UN", "MSG_CTRUNC", "MSG_DONTROUTE", "MSG_DONTWAIT", "MSG_EOF", "MSG_EOR", "MSG_FLUSH", "MSG_HAVEMORE", "MSG_HOLD", "MSG_OOB", "MSG_PEEK", "MSG_RCVMORE", "MSG_SEND", "MSG_TRUNC", "MSG_WAITALL", "NI_DGRAM", "NI_MAXHOST", "NI_MAXSERV", "NI_NAMEREQD", "NI_NOFQDN", "NI_NUMERICHOST", "NI_NUMERICSERV", "NOCTTY", "NONBLOCK", "PF_APPLETALK", "PF_CCITT", "PF_CHAOS", "PF_CNT", "PF_COIP", "PF_DATAKIT", "PF_DLI", "PF_ECMA", "PF_HYLINK", "PF_IMPLINK", "PF_INET", "PF_INET6", "PF_IPX", "PF_ISDN", "PF_ISO", "PF_KEY", "PF_LAT", "PF_LINK", "PF_LOCAL", "PF_MAX", "PF_NATM", "PF_NDRV", "PF_NETBIOS", "PF_NS", "PF_OSI", "PF_PIP", "PF_PPP", "PF_PUP", "PF_ROUTE", "PF_RTIP", "PF_SIP", "PF_SNA", "PF_SYSTEM", "PF_UNIX", "PF_UNSPEC", "PF_XTP", "RDONLY", "RDWR", "SEEK_CUR", "SEEK_END", "SEEK_SET", "SHUT_RD", "SHUT_RDWR", "SHUT_WR", "SOCK_DGRAM", "SOCK_RAW", "SOCK_RDM", "SOCK_SEQPACKET", "SOCK_STREAM", "SOL_SOCKET", "SO_ACCEPTCONN", "SO_BROADCAST", "SO_DEBUG", "SO_DONTROUTE", "SO_DONTTRUNC", "SO_ERROR", "SO_KEEPALIVE", "SO_LINGER", "SO_NKE", "SO_NOSIGPIPE", "SO_NREAD", "SO_OOBINLINE", "SO_RCVBUF", "SO_RCVLOWAT", "SO_RCVTIMEO", "SO_REUSEADDR", "SO_REUSEPORT", "SO_SNDBUF", "SO_SNDLOWAT", "SO_SNDTIMEO", "SO_TIMESTAMP", "SO_TYPE", "SO_USELOOPBACK", "SO_WANTMORE", "SO_WANTOOBFLAG", "SYNC", "TCP_MAXSEG", "TCP_NODELAY", "TRUNC", "WRONLY"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What OS are you on? `SO_PEERCRED` is Linux only, and is [only defined in Ruby if it exists on the platform](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v1_8_7_358/ext/socket/socket.c#L4530-L4532).

Compare:

```
$ uname
Linux
$ ruby -e "require 'socket'; puts Socket.constants.include? :SO_PEERCRED"
true
```

and

```
$ uname
Darwin
$ ruby -e "require 'socket'; puts Socket.constants.include? :SO_PEERCRED"
false
```